Using local git username and email on remote machine
I am currently working with a team of several people on single repository. All is fine when we are developing on our branches and local machines. However we also have a remote machine which we use it to run the project and sometime due deadlines we just ssh into the remote machine and develop inside the repository directly.
Since every time the git credentials needed to be changed it causes a problem and if we define a common credential like server/server@mail.com it cause a problem on who did the commits
Is there a way to transfer the git credentials inside remote machine repository?

To be honest, you don't really want to do that. It would be much better to develop a quick automated deploy method that anyone can use to update the remote fast, rather than each work on the same remote.

To answer your actual question as asked, though, I have a question: does each user login with their own account to the remote, and then all use the same sandbox? If so, each user could have their own user config that gets read from their home directory. If not, the problem will be much trickier to solve.

To test the algorithm we usually do quick tests on server and when there is a bug even though we are using our own machines, we use the ssh connected editor usually vs-code to quick edit/fix/add feature etc.. to continiue development

And if I understand correctly, you want the commit name and e-mail to depend on who's doing the commit, in which case each user should run git config --global user.name "my name" and git config --global user.e-mail "me@mail.ext" and that might be enough,.

Since there are quick changes and we are small team we can manage but I don't see how we can deal with this problem if we had 2-3 more active developers

OK, then the real question is: on the remote, do you each have your own account or not?

I want my defined --local or --global to be effective --local of remote repository I am connected

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes we all have our own github account

I will be back the office is closing in my timeline

TL;DR
Each user has their own global ~/.gitconfig on the remote, where they can save settings specific to themselves.
Details
While I don't know if any way for the local and global git config files to be "forwarded" to the remote (i.e., for ~/.gitconfig and .git/config on your own machine to be effective on the remote), each user can have their own ~/.gitconfig on the remote server, which will be effective for them there.
Since the key thing you want is for commits made on the remote to reflect the user who made the commit, each user should run these commands on the remote:
git config --global user.name "My name"
git config --global user.email "me@mail.ext"

or maybe even copy their whole ~/.gitconfig from their own machine to the remote.
Then when any user does a commit on the remote, their name and e-mail will be used to create the commit.
In order to avoid conflicts between users, avoid setting the local sandbox config for these settings, because the same local sandbox config will be shared among all the users.

I understand, I was just wondering is there a way to make it simple like when ssh into a remote repository on other machine from vscode an extention or a feature just changed the git credentials when you commit, push, ... etc and return it back to original

Well, you're mixing two things here: when you commit, that uses your user.name and user.email, but when you push/fetch/pull, that's a different thing altogether. That, you can forward, and I believe VSCode does that by default, and alternatively if you're using an ssh-agent to connect remotely, with agent forwarding enabled, your forwarded ssh key will be used to connect to GitHub with your account.

On push and pull there is no problem as you said vscode and our user credentials deal with correctly. I was trying to find a way for commits

Ah, OK, then the best I can offer is the answer I wrote, I am not aware of any automated config forwarding mechanism, sorry.

After searching I found a VS Code extension which enable fast switching between git identities

Git-Identity switcher


How does this answer the question about "transfer the git credentials inside remote machine"? Can the plugin do that?

Furkan, that's a cool plugin, thanks for pointing it out.

@j6t I would say this answer solves the X behind the question, if not exactly the Y as asked.

The plugin doesn't solves the problem, it is just convenient and fast to just change credential with button.
My question was, is there a way to not do that and make VS Code or any editor to use my local git credentials(system or global) when I remote ssh into a remote server and make commits
